# Python MVC-file-separation

Tags: design-patterns, python, code-quality

I'm used to programming in Java, so my view of these things is quite Java based but I doubt this is the correct way of writing Python code. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106896/how-many-python-classes-should-i-put-in-one-file link which asks a similar question to what I am about to ask.

In Python, when creating an MVC application, does it make sense to put all the classes in one file (module) as each part of the MVC application does technically belong together?

In Java, the idea would surely be to split these files as we might want to swap out either part of the MVC combination for another part. That is one of the advantages of writing MVC code (though in practice, might happen rarely). Still, I would opt to create a file for each part of the MVC code. A class for the model, view and controller.

Now, I can kind of get grouping `objectGUI, objectModel, objectController` in one module. As together they form `object`. But on the other hand, that feels kind of wrong from the Java background.

Is there a good rule of thumb for how splitting into modules actually works in Python. Is MVC even a strong thing in Python? (In my mind, Python is still mostly for glue code and scripts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, a file is a unit of import. So it makes sense to put things that belong together in the same file, and things that don't, to separate files.

Web frameworks like Django by default expect you to put your models in `models.py`, and your views / controllers in `views.py`. In large applications, these files are actually split, usually by subject area. Django also allows you to compose a whole web app from several reusable 'applications', each with its own structure.

It is easy to split a large file into several files without breaking existing code in Python. You just re-export the names from a split-out file, like this:

(views.py)

```
# These used to be defined here, now moved to premium_views.py 
from premium_views import FancyFeatureView, ExtraSnazzyView

class StandardView(...): ...
```

Now you can `from views import FancyFeatureView`, as if it were completely defined there. There's even a pattern of having such files that *only* re-export things from a bunch of other modules, so that these other modules can be changed as authors see fit without affecting normal client code.

Another consideration could be testing. What you want to test under significantly different setups likely belongs to different modules (files).

Comment: I disagree - in python the unit of import is the __module__ which is either a single file or a directory structure containing `__init__.py`, either can be built &/or compressed into an .egg or wheel.

Comment: Oh thank you. Your example of views does make sense from the point of view that they are all "views" so you can pick which one you need. But I suppose that in Java I might be more tempted to group the views more closely to the domain they belong to.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: this is fair. A file is _a_ unit of import; other, more complex units exist, as you noted.

Comment: @DylanMeeus: you can group things as you see fit; Python is more flexible in this regard than Java. Python lacks the strict Java-style package structure with canonical names; you can adhere to it if you want to (use absolute imports), or not. If you want to group views by domain, you're free to do so, either by putting them all in the same multi-file package, or in the same file. One important note: it's an anti-pattern for a deeper-level module to import something _directly_ from its ancestors; it's prone to circular import errors. Importing from sister packages is OK.

Comment: @DylanMeeus - While circular imports are something to avoid wherever possible python is actually very well tolerant of circular dependencies - module initialisation only occurs on the first import of a module. The main reason to avoid them is that it becomes a nightmare when re-factoring.

Answer (score 1):

In python you can use the [modules](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html) structure to group files by functionality and to control what is normally available. A module is a directory with several python files, and potentially sub-modules, and **must** contain a `__init.py__` file. This file can be used to control the public interface of the module.

If you have a module, *containing an `__init.py__` file,* called `fred` then you can `import fred` and access its members as `fred.item_name` or `from fred import item_name` then use `item_name`.

It is important to note the python practice of having, in each file, a section beginning with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

The code within the scope of this `if` statement will be executed **only** if that file is invoked directly - this allows modules to contain executable standalone utilities while still being importable as libraries by other modules or for providing standalone tests at the file or module level.

It is important to note that when the individual files in a module or the whole module are imported into a higher level item they will be byte compiled from `.py` to `.pyc` files which speeds up subsequent imports and general performance, *(on the first import of any session or run the time stamps are checked between identically named `.py` to `.pyc` files to check if recompilation is needed)*.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and also for your explanation about the __init.py__. I am extremely new to Python and did not know this :-)